# Python Gui: Which framework would be the best to display arrays

Tags: python, arrays, user-interface, maze

I was wondering which gui library would be appropriate to display a maze (a NxN array) and being able to fill each cell with a colour to represent states of that cell. I will also be generating a path from one part of the maze to another, and would like to display such path.

I need to choose a Gui framework for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: 2x2 array ... y u no use ascii art?

Answer (score 3):

[pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) is a nice library for making games but could also be useful here. You can start simple by just drawing squares. Later you can change the code to use sprites if you want to make it more visually appealing.

Check out some of the examples of [maze games](http://www.pygame.org/tags/maze) written using pygame.